# Type aliases and template template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, type-deduction

### Problem:

I have noticed that there is a bit of an inconsistency during template template deduction when using type aliases. In particular a type alias can be used as template template argument but is not deduced as one.

### Example:

We will use `Matched<Type>` to see if `Type` is an instance of a templated type.

```
template <typename T>
bool Matched = false;

template <template <typename> typename F, typename T>
bool Matched<F<T>> = true;
```

Now define a type alias

```
template<typename T>
using Alias = std::tuple<T,T>;
```

And my problem is that `Matched<Alias<int>>==false`. However `Alias` can be used as a template template argument, for example:

```
template<template<typename> typename F>
using ApplyInt = F<int>;
```

Then `ApplyInt<Alias>` works fine.

To recap, in `ApplyInt<Alias>` is treated as a template template argument but not in `Matched<Alias<int>>`. I find this a little stupid because I think about type aliases as functions on types and I would like to work with them. Right now, type aliases are treated as second class citizens compared to types and this makes hard to work with them in a generic way, such as composing or transforming them.

### Possible ways out:

1.Change deduction rules such that type alias is detected as template template argument. This would make `Matched<Alias>==true`.

2.Allow usage of `using` in template declaration like this:

```
template<template<typename> using T, typename T>
bool Matched<F<T>> = true;
```

### Question:

Is this behavior intentional? Is this an oversight? Was this noticed and will it be fixed in a future version in c++?

---

As a side note: The similar problem is with variable templates. Why cannot we write?

```
template <template<typename> auto Var>
auto VarForInt = Var<int>;
```

---

Edit(after accepting the answer):

I'm really puzzled by the type deduction. When we store a type alias in a helper class

```
template<template<typename> typename F>
struct Helper{};
```

and we have a function

```
template<template<typename> typename F>
void foo(Helper<F>){}
```

We can call `foo(Helper<Alias>{})`. Isn't `Alias` "deduced" in the function call? Or this is not called type deduction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is intentional. Alias templates are indeed, as you said, somewhat of a "second class citizen". To start with, alias templates cannot be specialized, that's a real big hint right there.

Now, their "lower grade" as evident in your example is all about [[temp.alias]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.alias):

> When a *template-id* refers to the specialization of an alias
>   template, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by
>   substitution of its *template-arguments* for the *template-parameters*
>   in the *type-id* of the alias template. [ Note: An alias template name
>   is never deduced. — end note ]

The above means, that when you write `Matched<Alias<int>>`, since `Alias<int>` refers to a specialization of the alias template, it's equivalent to *directly* writing `Matched<std::tuple<int,int>>`. And it's quite obvious why that doesn't match the specialized variable template.

It's not an oversight, nor is it going to be fixed. Alias templates are there to provide a shorthand for more complex template expressions. And you wouldn't want the wrong overload to be called, or the wrong template specialization instantiated, because you used a shorthand instead of the whole complex expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Therefore I have to change a little bit my mental model how I think about type aliases.

Comment: I'm still puzzled by something. In a special case I can deduce a type alias, see an edit at the end of my question. What is going on?

Comment: @tom - If you have another question, please post it as such (and link back to this one if you'd like). Broadening a question after the fact is kinda poor SO etiquette.